# How to store objects of a mutable Array into another mutable array in form of arrays.?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutable` array which contains some objects and I want to store these objects into a different Mutable array in the form of different arrays.

For ex: I have an array named sessionArrayType4 which has these objects.

```
"New Attendee Reception",
"Attendee Reception",
"Banquett",
"Tour and BBQ"
```

And I want to store in another Mutable array named globalSessionArray and I'm expecting result something like below.

`(("New Attendee Reception"), ("Attendee Reception"), (Banquett), (Tour and BBQ))`

Here is my code:

```
if(self.pickerSelectedRow == [self.typePickerArray objectAtIndex:3])
{
    for (int i =0; i< [self.sessionArrayType4 count]; i++)
    {
        if(self.displayTime == [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"start_time"])
        {
            [self.sessionRowArray addObject:[[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_name"]];
            self.rowCount = self.rowCount + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            [self.sessionRowArray removeAllObjects];
            self.displayTime = [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"start_time"];
            [self.sessionRowArray addObject:[[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_name"]];

            [self.globalSessionArray addObject:self.sessionRowArray];

        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting output something like this:

`((Tour and BBQ), (Tour and BBQ), (Tour and BBQ), (Tour and BBQ))`

Comment: replace if(self.displayTime == [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"start_time"]) with if([self.displayTime isEqualToString:[[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"start_time"]])

Comment: Can you please describe your objects better; what you have described is an array of strings, but your code shows that you are actually storing "proper" objects.  Please post the definition of that object.

Comment: @Girish : i understand that but how does that going to make any effect on my output coz any way it's going inside the loop.

Comment: @Zac24 I just point out one mistake from your code.

Comment: oh okay.. but i need some other solution. thx anyway.

Comment: use NSdictionary or mutableDictionar for this type of task its much easier  and proper

Comment: @NitinGohel: okay, that i'll take care from next time but can you help anyway now.?

Comment: @trojanfoe : I'm just a newbie, I understand what you asking for but i don't know how should i define that exactly.

Comment: I just want to see *what* is being stored in the array; is it a dictionary or a custom object?

Comment: ohkay. I'm retrieving the information from the array of dictionaries and trying to store in the form of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to alloc/init your values into an object for each iteration of the for loop or else it will continually stick in memory and overwrite itself.

```
if(self.pickerSelectedRow == [self.typePickerArray objectAtIndex:3])
{
    NSArray *
    for (int i =0; i< [self.sessionArrayType4 count]; i++)
    {
        NSObject *myNewObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        if(self.displayTime == [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"start_time"])
        {
            myNewObject = [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_name"];
            [self.sessionRowArray addObject: myNewObject];
            self.rowCount = self.rowCount + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            [self.sessionRowArray removeAllObjects];
            //NSLog(@"%@",self.sessionRowArray);
            self.displayTime = [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"start_time"];
            myNewObject = [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_name"]];
            [self.sessionRowArray addObject:myNewObject];
            // NSLog(@"%@",self.sessionRowArray);
            [self.globalSessionArray addObject:self.sessionRowArray];
            // NSLog(@"%@",self.globalSessionArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [self.globalSessionArray addObject:self.sessionRowArray]; this line add Array in to array. my frnd

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate an temp array in for loop to get a final array of arrays.

The code is very confusing but you can modify like below to get correct result:

```
    if(self.pickerSelectedRow == [self.typePickerArray objectAtIndex:3])
    {
         for (int i =0; i< [self.sessionArrayType4 count]; i++)
         {
             if(self.displayTime == [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"start_time"])
         {
        [self.sessionRowArray addObject:[[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_name"]];
        self.rowCount = self.rowCount + 1;
    }
     else
     {
         [self.sessionRowArray removeAllObjects];
         NSMutableArray* tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //NSLog(@"%@",self.sessionRowArray);
        self.displayTime = [[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"start_time"];
        [tempArray addObject:[[self.sessionArrayType4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_name"]];
        // NSLog(@"%@",self.sessionRowArray);
        [self.globalSessionArray addObject:tempArray];
        // NSLog(@"%@",self.globalSessionArray);
    }
```

Comment: if you are allocating a temporary array and not adding it's object to globalSessionArray then what's the point of doing this.?

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
if(self.pickerSelectedRow == [self.typePickerArray objectAtIndex:3])
```

This expression and similar ones look like incorrect, because the left value look likes int or NSInteger and right value is NSObject. If they are both NSObjects then use isEqual instead.

2)

```
sessionArrayType4
```

it is correct, but no serious programmer uses such names for variables.

3)It is hard to understand what do you want because of incomplete code and a lot of NSLog calls. You have also added JSON code which is particularly incompatible with a previous part of code.

So edit your code first